# Pick up the button that triggered the event

Tags: jquery

guys.

trying to get the button that was clicked, but the code get all the buttons with the class.

Anyone can help?

https://output.jsbin.com/comisateko

Comment: In future, you'll get a better response if you provide some code for us to debug. Inside the click event $().click(function(){....}) you can refer to the button that was clicked as $(this), alternatively you can include the element parameter in the event function, $().click(function(index,element), and refer to it as element.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is something that you need

```
$(function addLicense(){

$('.btn-add').each(function(index){
$(this).click(function(){
  var input = $(this).siblings('input');
  var value = input.attr('value');
  if(value >= 0){
    input.attr('value', ++value);
  }
})
});

$('.btn-sub').each(function(index){
$(this).click(function(){
  var input = $(this).siblings('input');
  var value = input.attr('value');
  if(value > 0){
    input.attr('value', --value);
    totalPessoa = value * 10;
   }
})
});

});`
```

Comment: That's it, Dralac. Tks!!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('.btn-add').click(function(){
    var target = $(this).prev('.input-value');
    if(target.val() >= 0){
      target.val(parseInt(target.val()) + 1);
    }
  });
```

then duplicate for subtract (you will need .next() instead of .prev()). The issue is that $('.input-value') retrieves all matching elements, so when you update you are updating all of them.